# rewriterule doubles first part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've spent hours researching and reriting this .hatccess code:-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^localhost

RewriteRule ^living-room-hallway/designer-cushions-pouffes http://jasmineway.co.uk/jw-ver3/contentdata.php?collection=1&type=1 [L]
```

(This link will not work as I am testing on my localhost, but couldn't use that in the link.)

The first click on the link "**living-room-hallway/designer-cushions-pouffes**" works fine, but now every link is preceded with "**living-room-hallway**" and the working link has now become "**living-room-hallway/living-room-hallway/designer-cushions-pouffes**"

Hopefully someone with a lot more knowledge than me can help me.

Comment: > and the working link has now become "living-room-hallway/living-room-hallway/designer-cushions-pouffes" << working link where? The problem may be not with Apache config but but with PHP/HTML and building the links. Do you have any example where this link is used/displayed?

Comment: This is the PHP for the link:-
<a href="living-room-hallway" id="livingLink">Living Room</a>
  <ul id="subNav2"><li><a href="living-room-hallway/designer-shelves-storage" id="lstorageLink">Shelves &amp; Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="living-room-hallway/designer-cushions-pouffes" 
  </ul>

Comment: Everything works fine until I try to introduce the virtual directories

Comment: Just checked the page source and the link is as it should be, but hovering on the link again shows the double living-room-hallway/living-room-hallway. Points to rewrite rules and.htaccess but it seems a very simple rule?